# android 7 "Network security configuration" what connections intercept?

Tags: android, security, ssl, pinning

i'm asking about [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html).

this system intercept only system URLConnection or also OkHttp, volley, apache HttpClient, any other possible way to do a connection from SDK and NDK?

in particular calls made from libs that i don't know how is done (aws, facebook, google, etc, etc)

Comment: it is intercepted by all (i personally experienced it) in okHttp and HttpClient.. talking about other possible case, it must be the same.

Comment: It definitely covers all sockets created in Java. `WebView` support was added later (8.0? 9.0?). I do not know if it covers sockets created in NDK code.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you reply i wil accept answer. so if i put certificate pinning and use google/facebook as SSO, or google maps i need to pin also that certificate? but i don't know if will change or not.

Comment: "if you reply i wil accept answer" -- personally, I would prefer a more complete answer than what I can offer you. "if i put certificate pinning and use google/facebook as SSO, or google maps i need to pin also that certificate?" -- usually, you only pin certificates that you control, unless the site provides specific pinning instructions.

Comment: If plaintextTraffic is allowed a native library could still use it's own SSL library to establish an HTTPS tunnel based on a plain TCP connection. If the library also handles all the certificate checking I doubt that the certificate config from Network security configuration will be effective in such a case.